# JavaScript - toDateString()

Tags: javascript, date, object

Image link is a code that increments the current date by 12 months.

Although I am getting the new date increased by 12 months but when I convert the new date to string by using `toDateString()` I don't get the output.

Please help me smart JavaScript people :)

[image]

Comment: You need to include more information for this question to be clear. To start, share the code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: Don't include the code in an image! Write it in your question. You can format it as a block of code by using the `{}` button.

Comment: Please replace the image with formatted code

Answer (score 0):

Use this function. At least this is the way i give format to my dates in my apps. By the way this is the way stack comunity is telling you to put your code in your question.

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
           var aux = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
           var year = aux.getFullYear();
           var month = (1 + aux.getMonth()).toString();
           var day = aux.getDate().toString();
           return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
       }
```

Hope this helps!